# Fubarino (microchip pic32mx), Second timer interrupt is not firing

Tags: interrupt

```
volatile uint32_t counter_timer = 0;
void __USER_ISR myISR() {
  counter_timer++;
  clearIntFlag(_TIMER_3_IRQ);
}
 
void __USER_ISR myISR_timer_four() {
  clearIntFlag(_TIMER_4_IRQ);
  TMR4 = 0x16E3600;
  Serial.print("hi\n");
    if(PORTAbits.RA10 != 1){
      LATAbits.LATA10 = 1;
    }
    else{
      LATAbits.LATA10 = 0;
    }
}
 
void setup{
  
  T3CONbits.TCS = 0b0; // Timer Clock Source Select bit
  T3CONbits.TCKPS = 0b000; //0b111; // Timer Input Clock Prescale Select bits
  T3CONbits.ON = 0b1; //0;//0b1;
  asm("nop \n");

  T4CONbits.TCS = 0b0;
  T4CONbits.TCKPS = 0b000;
  T4CONbits.T32 = 0b1;
  TMR4 = 0x16E3600; // half of 48mHz.
  T4CONbits.ON = 0b1;
 
  setIntVector(_TIMER_3_VECTOR, myISR);
  setIntPriority(_TIMER_3_VECTOR, 4, 0);
  clearIntFlag(_TIMER_3_IRQ);
  setIntEnable(_TIMER_3_IRQ);
 
  setIntVector(_TIMER_4_VECTOR, myISR_timer_four);
  setIntPriority(_TIMER_4_VECTOR, 1, 0);
  clearIntFlag(_TIMER_4_IRQ);
  setIntEnable(_TIMER_4_IRQ);
  
 
 TRISAbits.TRISA10 = 0;  // Fubarino onboard yellow led
}
 
void loop() {
delay(500);
Serial.println(counter_timer);
Serial.println(TMR4, DEC);
}
```

Hi,

i wanna use multiple interrupts, i got the information from a document i got from: Majenko Technologies.
the interrupt bound to Timer3 works, this was the example code in the pdf.
now i "assembled" a second interrupt bound to timer4, copy, paste and adapt, but that isn't working.

i can print the "content" of the timer4 register and it's running.

have i done something wrong?
search engine didn't yield a answer.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that you need to combine the even and the next odd timer (see datasheet of the microchip pic you're using) to form a 32 bit timer.